# Simple Keystroke Dynamics (KD) Measurement with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-dynamics, keystroke, biometrics

I want to develop a simple app to measure dwell time and flight time (see http://www.techrepublic.com/article/reduce-multi-factor-authentication-costs-with-behavioral-biometrics/6150761) in a text area / box. how can I use keypress() or keydown() up() methods to record these events?

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why this would not be worth it. Just because Javascript can be modified on the client side does not mean an attacker could reproduce an actual user's typing patterns.

Doing this on the client side has the added benefit of keeping the user's data private (e.g. you're not actually collecting user's keystrokes, but only information related to their typing patterns).

I'm sure there are still privacy concerns, but this is a very interesting authentication (or auditing/detection) control.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this approach would not be fruitful in a real-world environment, because whatever processing you do in Javascript is, in line of principle, easily modifiable by the user, by using a simple javascript debugger or programs like Firebug.

That said, you could measure the two metrics in this way:

- *dwell time* = time between `keydown()` and `keyup()`. In your `keydown()` method save the current time and in the `keyup()` compute the twell time as the difference between the current time and the `keydown()` time.
- *flight time*: from the figure of the article you linked I can't easily understand how it is defined, but I would compute it as the difference between when you left the last key (`keyup()`) and when you start pressing the next key (`keydown()`). So in `keyup()` save a time, for instance `last_key_time`, and in `keydown()` compute the flight time as current_time - `last_key_time`

Comment: Thats true, but as @zeitgeist has mentioned, it does not matter because the attacker does not know the user's typing patterns, which means that even though he could fake pretty much anything he wants, he cannot know what he wants to fake.

Comment: I don't agree. The attacker can first model the typing pattern (using machine learning techniques, the same that a recognizer would use on server side) and then reproduce.

Comment: I don't see how an attacker would do that, because he/she would have no starting point or any other information available about what he is trying to reproduce, unless he is able to inject code into the webpage the user is typing his password into. But maybe I'm missing something :)

Comment: You can inject client-side code into web pages using Cross-site scripting techniques: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: That's true, so in case there'd be a XSS vulnerability, the keystroke measurement would have no effect, because the attacker would be able to reproduce it, but the normal password protection would still be in effect. Therefore, the keystroke measurement could never reduce security, but only increase it in case there is no XSS vulnerability, isn't that correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This kind of weak biometrics should be used only in multiple-factor authentication, such as password + keystroke. That said, my personal opinion is that this particular modality is easy to fake, and I would not trust it to add more security to an authentication mechanism. :)

Comment: @AndreaSpadaccini It's a duty for the web developer to prevent any Cross-site vulnerability or he'll have more problems than this keystroke stuff. this argument doesn't hold water anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VDMPt/ [source](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

But as Andrea said, is not worth it since Javascript is client side

```
var xTriggered = 0;
$('#target').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
   xTriggered++;
   var msg = 'Handler for .keyup() called ' + xTriggered + ' time(s).';
  $.print(msg, 'html');
  $.print(event);
});

$('#other').click(function() {
  $('#target').keyup();
});
```